# hook with form Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop

guys (and ladies)

I like to ask you how to build the forms (formbuilder) in Prestashop 1.7 for the current 2020 year.

I created module with classes and hooks, but I can't find the info on how to create forms via "classes" and "controllers".
I'd happy to have something like this:

[image]

What have already done:

- created custom module
- created custom hook
- custom .tpl from /module/templates/front/custom.tpl is added to the hook and displays data correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using form builder in your .php file (or controller)

```
return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'switch',
                    'label' => $this->l('Live mode'),
                    'name' => 'TESTONE_LIVE_MODE',
                    'is_bool' => true,
                    'desc' => $this->l('Use this module in live mode'),
                    'values' => array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 'active_on',
                            'value' => true,
                            'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id' => 'active_off',
                            'value' => false,
                            'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'col' => 3,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-envelope"></i>',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Enter a valid email address'),
                    'name' => 'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL',
                    'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'name' => 'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD',
                    'label' => $this->l('Password'),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```